# Why doesn't ngOnInit varible change affect the html in angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have user object that i am subscribing to. If the user is equal to a certain name, than it shouldn't show a button. I don't know why it doesn't affect the ngIf in html.

My Html

```
 <input *ngIf = "showDelete" type = "button" (click) = 
 "deleteCustomer(customer._id)" value = "Delete" class = "btn btn-danger">
```

My ngOnInit in appcomponent.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {

let showDelete:boolean =true;

this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
  this.username = profile.user.name

  if (this.username=="admin"){

    showDelete=false;
  }
},
```

If i console.log the this.username and show delete i get the expected values, but it is not changing the logic in html

Comment: simply move the `showDelete` variable outside of your `ngOnInit()` function up to you component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the `showDelete` variable as part of your component so that it is accessible from the template:

```
public showDelete: boolean = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.username = profile.user.name;
        if (this.username == "admin") {
            this.showDelete = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no access to showDelete from the template, because it is defined within ngOnInit()

Try to define it like this:

```
 class MyClass {
   showDelete:boolean;

   ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.username = profile.user.name
      if (this.username=="admin"){
        this.showDelete = false;
      }
    }
}
```